# Cannot instal npm, ERR! errno -4058

Tags: node.js, cypress, npm-install

I wanted to learn cypress and started to follow step by step on cypress tutorial here. But when to started to: npm install then such a wild error appeared:

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Kamil\Desktop\Kurs/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Kamil\Desktop\Kurs\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Kamil\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-19T20_43_21_108Z-debug-0.log
```

What i did:

1. i run: npm install -g nodemon
2. deleted: package-lock
   but the there is still a problem

I need this to continue a cypress course

Answer (score 1):

The error says there is no `package.json` file in the directory you're installing in.

Do an `npm init` and fill the details in, or just do `npm init -y` (make sure you're in the right directory).

Once done, do `npm i` to fix the error. You should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You are either in the wrong folder or you may have deleted `package.json` by accident.

You must run `npm install` from a folder where there is a `package.json` present.